# Create directory with UTF-8 name in Vim

Tags: vim, mkdir

I can not create a directory in russian (UTF-8) using vimscript in WinXP.

For example

```
:call mkdir("привет")
```

creates directory with `РїСЂРёРІРµС‚` name instead of `привет`.

I have also tried

```
:call system("mkdir привет")
```

with the same result.

Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe adjusting the 'encoding' option would help?

Comment: 2Laurence Gonsalves: yep if I set up it to 'cp1251' - I suppose the one russian winxp uses - then it works.

Comment: 2Laurence Gonsalves: But I have to convert `привет` from UTF-8 to cp1251. Is there a way without explicit conversion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found it.

I should use iconv function:

```
:call mkdir(iconv("привет", "utf-8", "cp1251"))
```

Comment: That looks like bad practice, given that you're moving out of UTF-8. You should probably be checking why UTF-8 names don't work for you.

Comment: @dionyziz, probably the answer is because he's on WinXP and the system locale is cp1251 and there is no way to set it to utf-8.

Answer (score 69):

What I usually do is I switch to the explorer mode with `:Explore` and press `d`. It asks me for the directory name, then.

- [`:h :Explore`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#:Explore)
- [`:h netrw-d`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-d)

Answer (score 31):

try this

```
:!mkdir "привет"
```

Comment: The same result -`РїСЂРёРІРµС‚`

Comment: this doesn't work on Win10 in general, but `:call mkdir("my_dir/")` would

Answer (score 2):

You can change encod. Add:

```
chcp 65001
:call mkdir("привет")
```

chcp 65001 - UTF-8

Comment: You mean you set the console to use UTF-8 (execute `chcp 65001` in the console) and only then launch Vim? For reference, [65001 is the pseudo-codepage for using UTF-8](//stackoverflow.com/a/1629454/2157640).